# TFS Kanban Board: Where do the defaults column mappings for a newly created team come from?

Tags: tfs

I just noticed that every time I create a new team in TFS, the default kanban column mappings are not what I want them to be. Where is the default defined? I thought maybe the default Project column mappings would be used for new teams but that doesn't seem to be the case. I also can't find it in processconfiguration.xml although I suspect it has something to do with mapping the column types with the states.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to **set the new team as project default**  and custom the columns in Kanban board? If yes, you can reference below screenshot to do that.

Generally we can [Add columns to your Kanban board](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/kanban/add-columns?view=vsts#track-kanban-column-status) and set the state mapping for the custom column, but you have to add the custom state (see the sample code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/work/customize/reference/change-workflow-wit?view=vsts#workflow-diagram-and-code-example)) for work items if there isn't the correct state for mapping.

[image]

Comment: @George Altenbaugh Have you resolved the issue? any update?